# reading cells using VB Scripting

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am able to read the values in the cells, which are the locations of 2 folders, but when I run the code I get path not found error at line 6.

```
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
fsource = ws.Cells(1, 3).Value
fdest = ws.Cells(3, 3).Value
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(fsource)
```

but when I directly give the path like this it's able to identify the path:

```
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\kaka\Desktop\Results")
```

Comment: What is the value of `ws.Cells(1, 3).Value`? Also, is this VBScript or VBA?

Answer (score 1):

If

```
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\kaka\Desktop\Results")
```

'works' and

```
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(fsource)
```

fails, then `fsource` is different from `"C:\Users\kaka\Desktop\Results"`. As `fsource` comes out of a cell, the first suspect is extra white space. So check for such differences.

Comment: Right you are. If you are suspecting trailing or leading spaces then you might want to add `Set folder = fso.GetFolder(Trim(fsource))` to your answer.